# Convert date to day of year in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-date-functions

How can I convert a column with a date e.g. '2012-08-03' to the day of year in Postgres?

Answer (score 25):

Use the [extract](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function:

```
select extract(doy from the_date_column)
from the_table
```